# javascript: creating a function

Tags: javascript, function

I am kind of oldskool and just getting back to learning about all the new stuff added to JS in the last 10 years or so (or just stuff I did now know about back then) and would like to know whats the difference between

```
function xyz() // I used to always use it like this
{}
```

and this that I keep seeing:

```
xyz:function()
{}
```

It also has a funny little comma with two or more functions like so:

```
xyz1:function()
{},
xyz2:function()
{}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's when you are creating an object with function inside it:

```
var functions = {

    xyz1:function(){},
    xyz2:function(){}

}
```

Now I can do:

```
functions.xyz1();
//or:
functions.xyz2();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
xyz:function()
{}
```

alone is invaid syntax. The `key: value` notation, however, is used in objects.

For example,

```
var functions = {
    xyz: function()
         {}
}
```

Then you can call it like `functions.xyz()`.

This is very popular these days with libraries like jQuery, where you are often working with objects which contain a set of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly valid ways of defining a function.

The second function is an example of Javascript object notation, and it can be leveraged to make a more easy to understand Object orientated javascript 'class'.

See my answer to this question to see an example of this:

[function in JSON format - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910811/function-in-json-format-possible/5910861#5910861)